Laravel PHPUnit - PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 102400 bytes)
We are experiencing apparent memory leaks with our Laravel 10 application tests.
We recently upgraded from version 8 to 10, hoping this would resolve the issue, however it has not.
Using https://github.com/Roave/no-leaks we were able to run our tests and identify that a majority (if not all) of the tests are producing memory leaks from the report no-leaks gives.
The interesting thing we observed is when we don't extend a test with the Laravel test case class PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase as BaseTestCase and instead use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase, that test will no longer output from no-leaks with a memory leak issue.
For example running a test with the following extended class gives a memory leak.
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

class SampleTest extends BaseTestCase

This PHPUnit extended class does not give a memory leak
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SampleTest extends TestCase

I'm wondering if this is an issue within Laravel or a configuration of Laravel that we have.

Did you change your PHP version? Maybe it's related to memory limit size in your php ini. But you should search for issues in your codes.

I am not sure if you are saying that, instead of doing extends BaseTestCase (and BaseTestCase = PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase as BaseTestCase) you are doing extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase, or that on your test class using whatever extends, you are not using the intermediary class and you are directly using PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase. Show 2 simple codes please just to be 100% clear. Are you also aware that if you use fake()->boolean (for example), that produces memory leaks? It must be fake()->boolean()

@matiaslauriti I updated the code in the post

@DrewGallagher Okay, I see the difference now, it is what I suspected, not what I wrote. So, BaseTestCase is an alias of initializing Laravel framework. When you use PHPUnit test case, you are never starting Laravel. So there is something wrong on your Laravel installation/configuration. Something is being loaded that is leaking memory. You can check how BaseTestCase works, and you will see that one method is being called and starts executing stuff so Laravel works. You can add logging or something in there and see what happens when you comment parts of the initialization, to narrow this

@matiaslauriti I wonder if it's a package that we are using?
Maybe I can comment out packages, install the existing packages in the compser.json, and then see if one is causing the leak with the test runs?
Otherwise, I'm not sure how to identify the memory leaks if it's internal to laravel or our setup of laravel.
Do you have any specific ideas on how to troubleshoot?

@DrewGallagher I never checked for memory leaks on Laravel. One way of doing this is what you said, create a new project and start adding packages and see if you start to have the issue. Are you using Facades a lot? Any type of $this->singleton() calls? What about static properties and variables?
